# Unable to install Cytoscape or update Java as required

Tags: java, installation, cytoscape

I've been trying to install Cytoscape 3.9.1 for Windows (64 bit) on my laptop PC, which is running Windows 10.

I downloaded the installer and tried to run it and a window duly opens, but then it just hangs there, with a circle of endlessly spinning dots, but ultimately doing nothing.  I've tried this a couple of times, but with the same result each time.

I downloaded and ran the 'System Checker Script' as advised, and it reported an error, which I think means that I need to update Java.  This was a surprise to me as my PC is regularly updated and I recall updating Java not too long ago.

The error message also refers to something called 'JAVA_HOME' not being set.  I'm not sure what this is, but I assume it will right itself once Java is correctly updated.

I followed the link given at the bottom of the error message to download Java (https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk11), found that the link is out of date, but got redirected to the new site. I clicked on the link to download 'jdk-11.0.14.1+1' as advised, which led to download of something called 'OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_11.0.14.1_1.msi'. When I try to run it, however, I get exactly the same as with the Cytoscape installer - a window appears with spinning dots, and nothing happens.

I'd like to attach a copy of the error file from the System Checker Script but, as there doesn't seem to be any way of doing that here, I've copied it below this message.  Is anyone able to tell me what the problem here might be and what I can do to get Cytoscape installed correctly?  Please let me know if you need any clarification about any of the above.

Thanks for any advice offered.

Regards,

John

### Output from System Checker Script

'jvmVariant' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

### Cytoscape System Requirements Checker for Windows

Target Cytoscape version: 3.9.0

Your Windows version is:

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1526]

Java is installed

### More details on Java

java version "1.8.0_321"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_321-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.321-b07, mixed mode)

Your system is 64 bit

JAVA_HOME is not set

Your Java Major version is 8
Problem: Your Java version is less than version 11

Your Java version is no higher than version 11 as required

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0 50723    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

The "app" store at https://apps.cytoscape.org is reachable

### Summary

Your system has some issues.
Please fix those and re-run this script again:

- You need at least Java version 11, but not greater than Java version 11
- Link to download Java: https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk11

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Check your path variable. Probably is pointing for java 8. Fix it so it points to java 11 installation (%JAVA_HOME%\bin. Also add a JAVA_HOME environment variable that points to your Java 11 installation (the base folder where you installed).

Comment: Hi,  That's something I'm really not very familiar with. However, I've looked around on the web and have found this guide: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-add-edit-a-path-variable-in-windows.   Can I ask if you think I need to edit User variables or System variables?  Looking in User variables, I see no reference to Java at all. In the System variables, the only Java reference I see is this: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath. Can you advise please on how I should edit?

Comment: javapath is probably Java 8. You can remove this entry, and use User variables to change the path, and add the java 11.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and advice. To be honest, I'm not at all confident about doing this and, as one of my most important work tools runs under Java, I don't want to crash the entire system.  I'll have to see if I can get some help with it.  Thanks for the pointers though.

Comment: As has already been stated, your problem is the installation of Java 11, which for some reason your system isn't allowing you to install.  The Cytoscape installer includes Java 11, so it's probably getting hung in exactly the same place.  My guess is that your machine is locked down in some way that's preventing the install from proceeding.  NOTE: you can safely have Java 11 and Java 8 installed on your machine at the same time, although Java 8 class files and jars will work with Java 11 99% of the time.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I am the administrator for my cocmputer, so I can't think of any restrictions in installing software that may exist. I certainly haven't encountered any in the three or so years I've had this machine.  I wonder if it might be worth completely uninstalling Java and then trying the Cytoscape install again and let it install Java at the same time?